# Client-Side socket.io not emitting data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've been attempting to get my code working for a while now, but this issue is something I have never seen before.

I am attempting to connect my client & server through port 8080, and this seems to be working perfectly fine. Server successfully shows when a user has connected & can emit events (client can obviously show this emitted data as well). However, when I attempt to send any data back to the server it just *fails*.

There are no errors, however after some time "undefined" values start appearing in browser's console, which links to JavaScript's file line `console.log(ping);`

Here is some of my code:

Node:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Listening on requests...");
});

var io = socket(server);

console.log("Running...");

io.on('connect', function(socket){
    console.log("Connection from %s", socket.id);
    socket.emit('ping', 'ping');
    socket.on('pong', function(pong){
        console.log(pong);
        socket.emit('ping', 'ping');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("User %s has disconnected", socket.id);
    });
});
```

Client-Side JavaScript:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

socket.emit('pong', 'pong');

socket.on('ping', function(ping){
    console.log(ping);
    socket.emit('pong', ping)
});
```

I am very confused and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help or explanation of what's happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to call this `socket.emit('ping', 'ping');` after this `socket.on('pong', function(pong){...}` at your server side.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Unfortunately it doesn't matter when I call it.

Comment: make a search on Google to find any bug in socket.io regarding that scenario and then put an answer :-)